# How to get this.props.params populated in react-router v1.0.0?

Tags: javascript, url, reactjs, url-parameters, react-router

When I try accessing `this.props.params`, it is undefined. `this.context.router` is `{}`.

I played with the different variations of adding contextTypes to my component:

```
contextTypes: {
      router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

but had no luck.

My main goal is to pass the current react-router url to the server.

Answer (score 0):

As shown here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v0.11.6/examples/query-params/app.js, you need to add the `Router.State` mixin:

```
var User = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ Router.State ],
```